# Get ASCII value from QString and replace it with other ASCII

Tags: c++, qt, ascii, qstring, iso-8859-1

I need to get ASCII value from each QString's elements, then replace it
with others ASCII. 
I have these QString: `QString s = ui->lineEdit_3->text();`
and `QString k = ui->lineEdit_2->text();`, then i converted s to Latin1 `s.at(i).toLatin1();` but when i print `f`, nothing happens.
This is my code:

```
QString s = ui->lineEdit_3->text();
QString k = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
QString f;
k.toInt();
s.toStdString();


for(int i; i<=s.length(); i++)
{
    f.append(QChar(s.at(i).toLatin1()+k.toInt()));
}

ui->lineEdit->setText(f);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `i<=s.length();` is not right. It needs be `i<s.length();`  What is the value of `k`?

Comment: What do you want to do? Feel free to use pseudocode. Describe what you want the behavior to be first. I'm guessing that you want to add a constant value to each element's ASCII code?

Comment: Please turn on compiler warnings, and fix them. You can do this by adding `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra` to your *.pro* file (assuming you have *qmake* project and are using Linux, Mac or Windows/MinGW).

Comment: After you have warnings on, compiler should warn that `i` is uninitialized. Fix that, as a starter. Then you'll want to check what `k.toInt()` actually returns (try `qDebug() << k.toInt();`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below demonstrates one solution. The *Offset* control determines by how much is the character code offset from the original value. Conversion to ASCII is unnecessary: Unicode code points correspond to ASCII where the ranges of the two overlap (i.e. 32 to 127, inclusive). The *Modulo printable ASCII range* option keeps the results within the printable ASCII range by performing addition modulo the range (i.e. the results are wrapped to fit in the range).

[image: screenshot]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/ascii-add-ui-51639347
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QWidget ui;
   QFormLayout layout(&ui);
   QLineEdit input("Hello, World!");
   QLabel output;
   QLineEdit offset;
   QIntValidator offsetValidator(-65535, 65535);
   QCheckBox ascii("Modulo printable ASCII range 32-127");
   output.setFrameShape(QFrame::Panel);
   layout.addRow("Input Text", &input);
   layout.addRow("Output", &output);
   layout.addRow("Offset", &offset);
   layout.addRow(&ascii);
   layout.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QFormLayout::AllNonFixedFieldsGrow);
   offset.setValidator(&offsetValidator);
   offset.setPlaceholderText("0");
   ascii.setChecked(true);
   ui.show();

   auto const calculate = [&] {
      bool limit = ascii.isChecked();
      auto text = input.text();
      int delta = offset.text().toInt();
      for (QChar &ch : text) {
         auto doLimit = limit && ch >= 32 && ch <= 127;
         ch = {ch.unicode() + delta};
         if (doLimit) ch = {((ch.unicode() - 32) % (128 - 32)) + 32};
      }
      output.setText(text);
   };
   for (auto ed : {&input, &offset})
      QObject::connect(ed, &QLineEdit::textChanged, calculate);
   QObject::connect(&ascii, &QCheckBox::toggled, calculate);

   offset.setText("1");
   return a.exec();
}
```